# Relation from Douady paper about circle homeomorphisms.

Tags: analytic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic, mobius-transformation, conformal-field-theory

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485890437) the authors write down the following relation (p. 5, the last equation before the 3rd section):
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-|z|^2}{|z-\zeta|^2}\right)=\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow \zeta}\left[L(z,r) - L(0,r)\right],\quad (*)$$
where $L(z_1,z_2)$ is the Poincaré distance between points $z_1$ and $z_2$ on hyperbolic unit disk $D$.

I know that geodesic length between two points $z_1$ and $z_2$ can be expressed as follows: consider the Möbius map of arc $(z_1,z_2)$ to diameter $(0,u)$, where
$$u = \left|\frac{z_2-z_1}{1-\bar{z}_2z_1}\right|,$$
then the geodesic length is
$$L(z_1,z_2)=\ln\frac{1+u}{1-u}.$$
Fine. However, I cannot rederive the expression $(*)$. Can anyone clarify this derivation?

Comment: Sadly, the both authors, while wonderful mathematicians, wrote a suboptimal paper. The limit in question is called Busemann function. It is better to compute it in the upper half plane model and then use a conformal change of variables. Did you check modern treatments of the  DE-extension?

Comment: @MoisheKohan no and I will be grateful for any modern references. Can you provide also some references for Busemann function?

Comment: For instance, J.Hubbard "Volume 1: Teichmüller Theory", section 5.1. As for Busemann functions: start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busemann_function).

Comment: @MoisheKohan seems useful. To be honest, first of all I would like to understand how this function can be derived from the difference of two geodiscs.

Comment: As I said, do it in the upper half-plane where the point at infinity is "infinity", i.e. you travel to infinity along a vertical geodesic. The computation becomes effortless, taking into account the fact that the Busemann function will be invariant under horizontal translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it directly for the unit disk.  It is convenient, though, to make a rotation so that $\zeta=1$. If I am not mistaking it also looks as if Douady included a factor of one half in the Poincaré distance.
Let $r=1-\epsilon$ and expand in $\epsilon\to 0^+$. Then
$$ u = \frac{|1-\epsilon-z|}{|1-(1-\epsilon)z|} = \left|1-\epsilon \frac{1+z}{1-z} + ...\right|  = 1-{\epsilon} \frac{1-|z|^2}{|1-z|^2}+ ...$$
so that $$\frac12 \ln\frac{1+u}{1-u} = -\frac12 \ln(\epsilon) -\frac12 \ln \frac{1-|z|^2}{|1-z|^2} + ... $$
The first part cancels against the $L(0,1-\epsilon)$ term.

Comment: Yes, Douady indeed included 1/2 factor into the metrics. Nice and simple, thank You!